# How to determine if another application or process is accessing a locally mounted drive?

Tags: c#, service, mount, drive

If two windows services are accessing the same Local mounted drive (ie. H:)

Is there an C# way to determine what service/process is currently accessing the mounted drive?

Background information:

I currently have one service mounting a UNC path to a local drive using WNetUseConnection (mpr) Win32.Dll.

Before the decision to to dismount is made, I need to know if the other service is using the mounted drive.

I have exhausted my searching skills trying to find an answer to this

Any help is appreciated

Thanks